# Accumulated sum of parent child hierarchy in Django

Tags: django, django-models, hierarchical-data

I want to create a hierarchy of costs in django and display the accumulated value of parent nodes in a parent-child hierarchy. I also want to show the child nodes values.

For this I have the following model:

```
class accounts(models.Model):
    account_nr = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_account_nr = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

a typical list of accounts would be:

```
account_nr    account_name    parent_account_nr
1000          project 1       null
1010          subproject 1    1000
1011          task 1          1010
1012          task 2          1010
```

I have another model in which I add values as a transaction:

```
class transactions(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_ID = models.ForeignKey(accounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    debit_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    credit_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I currently have the following view which shows me the accumulated entries into the transactions model:

```
def home(request):
    account_query = accounts.objects.all() \
    .annotate(Sum('transactions__debit_value')) \
    .annotate(Sum('transactions__credit_value')) \
    .order_by('account_nr')
    args = {'account_queryx': account_query}
    return render(request, 'home.html', args)
```

with the following template I can view the accumulated entries in the model.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Omschrijving</th> 
      <th>Debit</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
    {% for account_query in account_queryx %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ account_query.account_nr }}</td>
      <td>{{ account_query.account_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ account_query.transactions__debit_value__sum}}</td>
      <td>{{ account_query.transactions__credit_value__sum }}</td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

the issue I can't get my head around is: How can I create a query which shows the accumulated values of parent nodes in the hierarchy of costs?

I've come across the following page which presents a solution in SQL with a recursive CTE.https://sqlsunday.com/2014/04/06/accumulating-in-a-hierarchy/
 However to my knowledge this doesn't work in Django.

What would be the best way to show accumulated values of child nodes in a parent-child hierarchy with Django?

Comment: It does not even work in (most) databases. This is T-SQL, not "vanilla" SQL. I think here it is better to do the recursion in Django (well not per se in the view, you can write the logic in a model as well). Or another option could be to make a "shadow table" that each time stores (and updates) the *transitive closure*) of the parent-child relation, and thus eases annotations.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Huh, aren't (recursive) CTEs pretty well supported these days? Even MySQL has it by now, or am I misreading your comment? I do agree about the use of the t. closure.